# Reducing spaces in a string each loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to print out 2 shapes made with *'s on the same lines.
The end result must look like this

```
//  * * * * *             *  
//  * * * * *            * *  
//  * * * * *           * * *
//  * * * * *          * * * *
```

The code I have works so far, yet i'm not sure how to decrease the spaces between the shapes with each loop.

Current Code:

```
String rectangleLine = "* * * * *";
int x = 1;
    for(int a = 0; a < 4; a++){
    String repeated = new String(new char[x]).replace("\0", "* ");        
    String line = rectangleLine + "             " + repeated; 
    System.out.println(line);
    x++;
}
```

The current result is:

```
* * * * *             * 
* * * * *             * * 
* * * * *             * * * 
* * * * *             * * * *
```

How would I go about decreasing the spaces each loop?

Comment: you can use another loop to change the number of spaces and stars

Comment: I would suggest you use only one * and count how many times it needs to be printed. Instead of `rectangleLine`

Comment: How exactly would I go about doing this? I don't have a whole lot of experience with java unfortunately @PeterLawrey

Comment: You can put another loop inside a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
int spaces = 13;
String stars = "*";
for(int i = 1;i<=4;i++){
    System.out.print("* * * * *");
    for(int j=1;j<=spaces;j++){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    spaces--;
    System.out.println(stars);
    stars+=" *";
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a homework writing service.  Please do not give users reason to believe otherwise.  Thank you.